# How I make select SQL with Arabic comma in SQLite

Tags: sql, c, sqlite, arabic

I'm trying to make select query with Arabic in C by using SQLite.

All things are fine but Arabic comma has problem.

It doesn't work at all only for Arabic comma.

```
sprintf(sql_query, "SELECT id, family_name, given_name, instr(normalized_given_name||normalized_family_name , '%s') FROM Database
WHERE (given_name||family_name LIKE '%%%s%%' OR normalized_given_name||normalized_family_name  LIKE '%%%s%%')", searchWord, searchWord, searchWord);
```

I make SQL query by using sprintf with sql_query value which is array of 4096.

> SELECT id, family_name, given_name,
>   instr(normalized_given_name||normalized_family_name , ،) FROM Database
>   WHERE (given_name||family_name LIKE %،% OR
>   normalized_family_name||normalized_given_name LIKE %،%)

Above SQL is what I get from log by printing the SQL query.

```
int result1 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(phonebook_Db, sql_query, -1, &main_stmt, 0);
while( (result2 = sqlite3_step(main_stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) 
{

~~ 

}
```

This works fine with other language and Arabic words.

It only has problem with Arabic comma that it returns no result.

Even though there is Arabic name which has Arabic comma, it is found with Arabic but if I add Arabic comma, it cannot be found.
(ex: ششطسببض، صصينس )

How can I get a right result with Arabic comma?

Comment: First: Instead of using `sprintf()` to insert values, use parameters and `sqlite3_bind_XXX()` functions with your [prepared statement](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) instead. Second: Do any of those columns contain strings with the character in question in them? Needs sample data - preferably as a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for easy copy and pasting into a test database.

Comment: I ask about if the values being tested include the comma because in any language I'm familiar with (Which granted doesn't include Arabic), having a comma in a given or family name is really unusual, and after creating a test table with values with that comma, `LIKE` matches it just fine. So I think it's a problem with your input, hence the request for sample data.

Comment: Test something much simpler when having issues like this.  This expression returned 1 (i.e. true) using version 3.27.2:  `SELECT 'ششطسببض، صصينس' LIKE '%،%';`  Just as Shawn points out, you suspect that it is problem with characters, but may be something else in your code.  (Also, as GeneCode points out, why are the single quotes around strings missing from the SQL statement show in the question?)

Comment: @shawn Thank you for kind answer. I will change my code and test it by your suggestion `sqlite3_bind_xxx()`. I only make simple string with mentioned in my question and test it so I don't have any other string currently. I've never test with other language with Arabic comma. But as I told, this logic works fine with other languages even though Arabic works fine. The only problem is Arabic comma.

Comment: @CPerkins I checked that it worked 'SELECT 'ششطسببض، صصينس' LIKE '%،%';'. I'm not sure why single quotes are missing in printed log but except for Arabic comma, it worked fine. I need to test more by following Shawn's suggestion. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is due to there is a space at the comma but your LIKE statement doesnt specify a space.  ششطسببض، صصينس (Here there is space there).

So you can try to change from

```
%،%
```

to

```
% ،%
```

But I am not sure if this is the issue or not. Just giving idea.

EDIT: another idea is to put quotes around the phrase %،%
Like so: '%،%'

maybe it might work.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference; the `%` wildcard eats up the space.